# How would I save custom data after the app closes?

Tags: swiftui, struct, save, persistence, appstorage

I am trying to store data after the app closes and one of the things I need to store is a variable that uses this struct

```
struct ToDoTasks: Identifiable, Hashable, Encodable, Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    var task: String
    var date: Date
}
```

The user can enter data where it is then stored here using the previous struct

`@State var items:[ToDoTasks] = [ToDoTasks(task: "Test", date: Date())]`

What would be the best way to save the items variable after the app closes?

I tried using @AppStorage but couldn’t get it to work.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/persisting-data

Comment: @Ashley 's answer is a great alternative to `@AppStorage` or `UserDefaults` when you want data persistence without using Core Data. However, I question the necessity of storing data AFTER the app closes, as opposed to saving it just BEFORE the app closes. It would seem to me that the app’s closing means the code stops running. I admit I am new-ish to Swift, however.

Answer (score 1):

In Apple's [ScrumDinger](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/getting-started-with-scrumdinger) sample they do the save in `ScrumsView.swift` like this:

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
...
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
            if phase == .inactive { saveAction() }
        }
```

Comment: This is what @AshleyMills 's comment was about. Her link goes straight to the relevant part of that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SO @Adam happy to help you with any other problems. And fyi Ashley is a he.